# PLINQ AsParallel error with datatable

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

I am trying to use `AsParallel` with the datatable

```
using System.Linq;


var row = from r0w1 in dt.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
          join r0w2 in curdt.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
          on r0w1.Field<string>("B") equals r0w2.Field<string>("cr_B")
          join r0w3 in tbmdt.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
          on r0w1.Field<string>("B") equals r0w3.Field<string>("tb_B") into ps
          from r0w3 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new string[] { serial_number++.ToString() }
          .Concat(r0w1.ItemArray.Concat
          (r0w2 != null ? r0w2.ItemArray.Skip(1) : new object[] { "", "", "", "" })
          .Concat(r0w3 != null ? r0w3.ItemArray.Skip(1) : new object[] { "", "", "", "" })).ToArray();
```

But I am getting an error here

```
system.data.enumerablerowcollection<system.data.datarow> does not contain a definition for 'Asparallel'
```

I am using visual studio 2008. Do I need any extra library for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea to use AsParallel in inner statements. You won't speed up DB querying.

Put it in the end, if you need to operate collection:

```
var row = from r0w1 in dt
          join r0w2 in curdt
          on r0w1.Field<string>("B") equals r0w2.Field<string>("cr_B")
          join r0w3 in tbmdt.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
          on r0w1.Field<string>("B") equals r0w3.Field<string>("tb_B") into ps
          from r0w3 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new string[] { serial_number++.ToString() }
          .Concat(r0w1.ItemArray.Concat
          (r0w2 != null ? r0w2.ItemArray.Skip(1) : new object[] { "", "", "", "" })
          .Concat(r0w3 != null ? r0w3.ItemArray.Skip(1) : new object[] { "", "", "", "" })).AsParallel();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned in the question, I cant even use `AsParallel` because of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `AsParallel` (or any linq extension methods as far as I know) on the `DataRow` class. You can use it on `DataTable` though, and then just use `DataTable.Rows`.

Also using `AsParallel` won't really do anything in your case, only do it when you need to query on different elements of a collection simultaneously when order, or intermediate results aren't needed.